# Quit terminal Mac application programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, terminal

I have a simple terminal app that I want to close after it finishes (actually close the terminal instance it opened).

There are many questions on how to kill mac applications, but none of them appear to apply to terminal mac apps.

I have tried running the following at the end of my program:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(0)
```

and

```
kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);
```

but none of them actually close the window. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or if this is even possible?

Comment: What if the user already has some other Terminal window open? I usually have at least a couple Terminal windows open, and I'd be more than annoyed if running some command caused Terminal to exit.

Comment: Right, I only want to close my Terminal app, I'm just not sure how to since it's not documented very well as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're getting at. Are you talking about Terminal.app, the terminal emulator that comes with MacOS X, or have you written some terminal emulator of your own?

Comment: I think he means that he wants the equivalent of quitting a script that you're running in terminal like Ctrl-c

Comment: I mean the single instance of Terminal.app that is opened to run my terminal app.

Comment: If this is like a shell script in a .command file, it does not open a new instance of Terminal.app, just a new window.

Comment: It's a .app file, I created a command-line app in Xcode

Comment: Umm...Simple answer: Don't make a command-line app.

Answer (score 1):

Simply executing:

```
exit(0);
```

... will immediately terminate any mac process, wether a terminal command line tool or a full GUI app.

You shouldn't do it in a GUI app because would bypass anything designed to save user data before quitting, but it's the correct function within terminal.

The terminal window will only be closed if your command line tool is not being run inside a shell. Even then, Terminal will only close the window if "when the shell exits" is set to "close the window" or "close the window if the shell exited cleanly".

The number `0` provided to exit signifies your tool exited cleanly. Return some other number to prevent the window from closing (and you should print an error message).